# Dockerfile for Python3 and OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ubuntu, dockerfile

I need to have a Dockerfile with Python3 and the latest version of OpenCV. The Dockerfile I have written is described below:

```
FROM ubuntu

#Install OpenCV
RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y cmake

RUN apt-get install -y gcc g++

RUN apt-get install -y python3-dev python3-numpy

# To support GUI features
RUN apt-get install -y libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev

# To support GTK 2
RUN apt-get install -y libgtk2.0-dev

# To support GTK 3
RUN apt-get install -y libgtk-3-dev

#Optional dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libjpeg-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libopenexr-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libtiff-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libwebp-dev

# Clone OpenCV repo
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git

#Compile
RUN mkdir /opencv/build && \
    cd /opencv/build
RUN cmake ..
RUN make
```

However, when i run it, it gives me the following error with `cmake`.

```
Step 17/27 : RUN cmake ..
 ---> Running in 3dca32df2036
CMake Error: The source directory "/" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
The command '/bin/sh -c cmake ..' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Do you know what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to chain the last `RUN` instructions:

```
#Compile
RUN mkdir /opencv/build && \
    cd /opencv/build && \
    cmake .. && \
    make
```

#### Explanation:

A `RUN` statement creates a new image layer and executes the specified shell command. This means that each `RUN` statement will run the command in a separate shell, so the current directory from the previous `RUN` will not be preserved (you can see that the CMake current directory is `/` by looking closely at the error message).
You can find more info about `RUN` statement in the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) and I also recommend reading [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run).